# fancybox -how to call a function when closing the fancybox plugin-i.e when I click on the cross icon

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

The cross button's class is fancybox-item and fancy-close using this i tried implementing this code but this is not working.Could someone please help me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            /*
             *  Open manually
             */
             $(".fancybox-item").click(function(){
                alert('close');
                });
});
```

Comment: Well, the proper class is `fancybox-close` and you don't need to bind a `click` to any of those selectors, use simple the `afterClose` callback to execute your function. See http://jsfiddle.net/DVVAM/

Comment: Fancybox exists in tow versions (1 & 2). Don't forget to add the version you are using next time : the documentation can differs.

Comment: @Maxooo : well, check the tags of the question, it says `fancybox-2`

Comment: Sorry about that. Anyway you can repeat it in title too ;)

Answer (score 1):

For FancyBox version 1:

```
$("....").fancybox({
  onClosed: function() {
    alert('close');
  })
});
```

For FancyBox version 2:

```
$("....").fancybox({
  afterClose: function() {
    alert('close');
  })
});
```